# Cannot sign transaction

Tags: web3.js

I have this code here and I get the sendAndConfirmTransaction function to not throw

```
withdraw = async (sourcePrivateKey, targetPublicKey, amount) => {
  try{
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
    const account = Keypair.fromSecretKey(sourcePrivateKey);
    const transaction = new Transaction().add(SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubKey: account.publicKey,
      toPubKey: new PublicKey(bs58.decode(targetPublicKey)),
      lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * amount,
    }));

    const signer = {publicKey: account.publicKey, secretKey: account.secretKey};
    console.log(signer.publicKey.toString());
    const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      transaction,
      [account],
    );
    return signature;
  }
  catch( error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') at .../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1483:47
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Transaction.compileMessage (/.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1482:18)
```

`at Transaction._compile (/.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1605:26) at Transaction.sign (/.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1704:26) at Connection.sendTransaction (/.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:7963:21) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (/.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:2155:21)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capitalization on the sender and recipient here is wrong:

```
const transaction = new Transaction().add(SystemProgram.transfer({
    // Wrong capitalization
    fromPubKey: account.publicKey,
    // Wrong capitalization too
    toPubKey: new PublicKey(bs58.decode(targetPublicKey)),
    lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * amount,
}));
```

So this should be

```
const transaction = new Transaction().add(SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: account.publicKey,
    toPubkey: new PublicKey(base58.decode(targetPublicKey)),
    lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * amount,
}));
```

I recommend you use Typescript instead of raw Javascript: All I had to do with your code was paste it into my code editor and tell my editor it was TS and it immediately told me the error was with the parameter name. As you saw yourself, Javascript's lack of "compile" time errors can lead to a lot more difficult debugging :).

Comment: Thank you so much!